# How to adjust image and text in ViewPager circle indicator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to put ImageView and TextView in ViewPager circle indicator. I want to display text below to Imageview, but the text is getting hide by footer which has circle indicator. Please suggest how can I adjust three of them in a layout. Layouts are :

ViewPager :

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- ViewPager -->

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
           <!-- Footer -->
        <include layout="@layout/footer"  />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Footer which has circle indicator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/btn1" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_celll" />

 <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/btn2"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_celll" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the layout1 which will be displayed in ViewPager :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="top|center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sp1" 
    android:layout_weight="0.7"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="First Layout First Layout First Layout First Layout "
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Lets say as of now you have three layouts -
1) Main layout (which has view pager)
2) footer layout
3) layout having imageView and textView

To achieve your goal, you can do below steps -
 remove "<include layout="@layout/footer" from mail layout and add it as a part of 3) layout.
 This footer view will also be part of viewPager.
```